# show ggplot2 title without reserving space for it

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to set titles to some ggplot2 charts, while leaving some without titles. Unfortunately, when title is set, the y axis and the plot shrink (see the plot on the right). I need to plot the title without changing the Y axis size, so that titled charts are on the same scale with the others (as in the middle plot).

```
grid.arrange(
  (ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) + geom_point()),
  (ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) + geom_point() + 
    geom_text(aes(22.5, 340, label="fake title",  vjust = 1, hjust = .5, show_guide = FALSE))),
  (ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) + geom_point() +
    labs(title="real title")),
  ncol=3)
```

[image: plot sample]

I cannot use fake empty-string titles on the other plots, because I am short on space.
I could use the `geom_text()` method, if anyone can tell me how to make it look less garbled.
So, how do I removing any reserved space for the title above the plot, while still showing the plot title on and at the top of the plot area? The latter is done with `theme(plot.title = element_text(vjust=-1))`.)

Comment: Instead of `geom_text`, use `annotate(geom = "text")`

Comment: @Gregor: I ended up doing what you suggested, so if you can write that as an answer I'll give the credit. If not, I will mark Matthew Plourde's answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `annotate` for this. If you use `geom_text`, it will print as many labels as there are rows in your data, hence the poor-looking overplotted label in your question. A painful work-around is to create a 1-row data frame to use as the data for the `geom_text` layer. However, `annotate` is intended for this sort of thing so you don't need a work-around. Something like:

```
 annotate(geom = "text", x = 22.5, y = 340, label="fake title")
```

is good practice. Annotate is also useful for adding single horizontal or vertical lines to a plot, or to highlight a region by drawing a rectangle around it.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**
Thanks to @baptiste for pointing out a more concise way to accomplish this. Given `p1`, `p2`, and `p3` from below:

```
pl = lapply(list(p1,p2,p3), ggplotGrob)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(do.call(cbind, c(pl, size="first")))
```

---

**Original answer**

You can build the ggplot grobs and standardize the `heights` parameter across plots:

```
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) + geom_point()
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) + geom_point() + labs(title="real title")
p3 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) + geom_point() + 
    geom_text(aes(22.5, 340, label="fake title",  vjust = 1, hjust = .5, show_guide = FALSE))

p1 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p1))
p2 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p2))
p3 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p3))

p2$heights <- p1$heights
p3$heights <- p1$heights

grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, ncol=3)
```

[image]

You can then use the title's `vjust` setting to move it off of the plot or further onto the plot, if you want:

```
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) + geom_point() + 
    labs(title="real title") + 
    theme(plot.title=element_text(vjust=-.3))
```

[image]

Comment: gtable is more suitable than grid.arrange, `pl  = lapply(list(p1,p2,p3), ggplotGrob); grid.newpage() ; grid.draw(do.call(cbind, c(pl, size="first")))`. Also note that `annotate()` would be better than geom_text since currently it stacks multiple versions of the text.

Comment: Thanks, @baptiste. I've updated the answer to include your suggestion.